# snipMate for vim

Tags: vim

I can't use snipmate on my vim. I installed it as explained

`filetype plugin on` in .vimrc

and unzipped all the content of snipMate.zip to my .vim folder...

Normally I have autocomplete too (mapped to TAB) after unzipping all the files, then my tab autocompletion doesn't work neither.

Maybe the cause that snipmate doesn't work is because my source files extensions are *.v. Maybe it is because of that, it doesn't work??

Can anyone help me with this, because this plugin together with autocompletion will help me a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have both snipMate and your auto-complete mapping on `<Tab>`; the last one wins. Check with

```
:verbose imap <Tab>
```

The file extension is not essential to snipMate; what matters is that the filetype is properly detected. Check with

```
:setl filetype?
```

You can manually `:setl filetype=...` to correct this, buy you probably want to tweak the filetype-detection if you use those file extensions frequently.

A good way to check what snippets snipMate has loaded is the auto-completion in insert mode via `<C-R><Tab>`.

If you continue to have problems, I recommend to disable other plugins and customizations first, and then try to add them back once snipMate is working.

Comment: Can I change the tab to another key for snippet completion? because I want to stay using tab for autocompletion of variable names etc

Comment: Yes, you have to edit `~/.vim/after/plugin/snipMate.vim`; it'll still return `<Tab>` when there's no snippet, though.

Comment: Everything works fine, I first disabled all plugins and now it works. But for syntax highlighting I add following: `au BufRead,BufNewFile *.* set filetype=newhorizon`  <br/> `au! Syntax newhorizon source $HOME/.vim/syntax/newhorizon.vim` And this changes the filetype which leads to snipmate not working  @Ingo Karkat

Comment: If you just want different syntax, use `:setl syntax=newhorizon` instead `:set filetype=`. If it's indeed a different filetype, you have to define / copy / symlink the snippets there.

Comment: If I paste `setl syntax=newhorizon`in my vimrc it doesnt work, but if I open a file and write `:setl syntax=newhorizon` there, then I have highlighting, autocompletion and snippets. Why is syntax not set in vimrc? And what do you mean with 'you have to define / copy / symlink the snippets there.'

Comment: The vimrc is for _global_ settings; you certainly don't want C or Java files all in that same syntax, do you? Learn how to set filetype-specific settings `:help filetypes`; I can't tell you all that here in the comments.